# CreateItem() untreated error return

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm having a strange behaviour after the last update with the createItem function of a datasource in create mode. My datasource is a mysql table.

I get it from my custom create functions as well as from the auto generated forms:

```
Exception caught: Exception caught: 8 exceptions caught: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'sb' of null; (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'sb' of null; (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'sb' of null; (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'sb' of null; (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'sb' of null; (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'sb' of null; (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'sb' of null; (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'sb' of null
at NewPage.Form1.Form1Footer.Form1SubmitButton.onClick:1:19
```

None of the fields are mandatory, ID is AI and no formats or regex are in place

Any ideas?

Comment: Was this working before? Seems to me that you are trying to read the value of a non existing widget.

Comment: It was in develpment so I wouldn't say it was something that was working and I agree that seems to be the case, but it's hard to debug which widget's value, specially since the auto-generated form has the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the issue.

I have a few query builder rules in place for many of my datasources, they respond to a widget that has a create mode datasource.

**When the createItem() event is called, all the elements of the datasoure in create mode are removed before being saved.** => is this the expected behavior?

Therefore the values of my widgets are null, since their datasources have been refreshed and filtered with the value in the query builder.

Long story short: don't bind query builder variables to values of widgets in create mode.

Comment: Yes, this is expected, as we reuse the same item for the next creation, so if you wanted to start creating a record you need the old record cleared out.

The error message seems pretty unhelpful in this case, although it did give a line number. Did that help or was it misleading?

Comment: Not really, becuase this error came from the only line in the button of the auto generated form and in my custom save function it only pointed to the createItem function or the saveChanges() function of the datasource